# Formatting issue with readme file on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, markdown

I have created a read me file and it looks fine on my computer; however, when I push it to my DevOps the format messes up, it keeps adding an unordered list like the following:
[image]

Here is how it looks on my computer, I am using VSCode, and the `Markdown Preview Enhanced` extension to auto populate the Table of Contents[image]

How can I fix this issue when publishing to Azure DevOps? Is that a problem with the extension?

Comment: I have tried to create a new README.md file in VS Code with the Markdown Preview Enhanced extension enabled and upload it by UI. But it did not reproduce your issue. I would like to know how you upload the file? Do you use any other related extensions in VS Code? Could you edit the question to provide the first part of your README.md file **in Azure DevOps**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markdown file must be compatible with the syntax definition in the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops.  This should ensure proper display.